# Xamarin Plugin.CloudFirestone - Stop Realtime update

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I can successfully use firebase realtime with xamarin using Plugin.CloudFirestone.

I use the listener this way:

```
CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.Collection("yourcollection")
                       .Document("yourdocument")
                       .AddSnapshotListener((snapshot, error) =>
                       {
                           ...
                       });
```

But when the user logout I need to stop listening. Does anyone know how to do it? I've read the official material but I couldn't get any information about it. thanks!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation on [detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#unity_5) shows, you can call `Stop()` on the object that is returned when you attach the listener:

```
DocumentReference query = db.Collection("yourcollection")..Document("yourdocument")

ListenerRegistration listener = query.Listen(snapshot => {
  foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot.Documents) {
    Debug.Log(documentSnapshot.Id);
  }
});
```

And then later:

```
listener.Stop();
```

This call will stop the listener from receiving further updates.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks so much for the guidance! Using the Plugin looked like this: 

IListenerRegistration listener = CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.Collection("yourcollection")
                       .Document("yourdocument")
                       .AddSnapshotListener((snapshot, error) =>
                       {
                           ...
                       });

and: listener.Remove();

Comment: Yeah, that might be the Xamarin variant of it. I picked the Unity example, since that's the only C# example in the docs.